# Android uses sdk attributes

Tags: android, sdk, version

I have a question about the android sdk.
I want the application to be avaiable for android 1.6 up to android 4.03.
I have recently been using the 1.6 sdk, but i need to block xlarge screens so i want to use a higher sdk.
Can i use the latest sdk and use the  with

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="4 " android:maxSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have recently been using the 1.6 sdk, but i need to block xlarge screens so i want to use a higher sdk.

No, you need to use a higher build target, so you can compile with a `<compatible-screens>` element in your manifest. This has nothing to do with `<uses-sdk>`.

> Can i use the latest sdk and use the with

It is not a good idea to use `android:maxSdkVersion`, as is explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max). Otherwise, this `<uses-sdk>` element is fine, though it has nothing to do with "block xlarge screens".

Comment: Because the block screens where introduced in android 3.0(maybe higher)m i need a higher sdk then 1.6. If i use the the android 4 sdk, can i run the application on a android 1.6 phone ?

Comment: @Ukjent: "i need a higher sdk then 1.6" -- you need to have the SDK libraries installed via the SDK Manager for API Level 9 or higher. "If i use the the android 4 sdk, can i run the application on a android 1.6 phone?" -- yes, so long as you do not attempt to use Java APIs that do not exist on an older device when running on an older device.